# Не переноситься текст на новую строку в БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql

Подскажите, как быть? Бот Телеграмм не хочет переносить данный текст, который на скрине — на новую строчку, управление главного меню идет через БД, как и что сделать в БД чтобы нормально было с новой строки?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3PMr.png]

Comment: Переносить текст где? В чём связь между БД и ботом? Покажите хоть какой-нибудь [mcve], а то непонятно вообще ничего

Comment: Дело в том,что я не могу в самом коде сделать так,чтобы перенос был на новую строку.

Comment: Ну так покажите уже хоть какой-нибудь код, наверное? Непонятно о чём реь